# Inside a DialogFragment the RecyclerView item width shrink before scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment, android-constraintlayout

[image]

I've attached 3 screenshots of a `DialogFragment`. In this dialog, I wanna show a `RecyclerView`. When the dialog opens, the width of first 2 items is shrunk. But after a little bit of scrolling when 3rd item comes up, it is displayed with expected width[Check screenshot 1 & 2]. If I continue scrolling from top to bottom then I see the rest of the items shown normally. Then again I scroll from bottom to top and surprisingly noticed that 1st and 2nd items are also shown as expected.
[check screenshot no. 3]

I would like to share my codes.

**From my Adapter class:**

```
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new CustomViewHolder(view);
}
```

**item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/modalityTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/modalityTitle"
        tools:text="X-Ray"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/statusImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/modalityTextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/modalityTextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_circle_outline_black_24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contrastTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/modalityTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/contrast"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contrastTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/modalityTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/contrastTitle"
        tools:text="Oral contrast"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bodyPartTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/contrastTitle"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/bodyPart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bodyPartTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/contrastTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/bodyPartTitle"
        tools:text="Chest"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/procedureTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bodyPartTitle"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/procedureDescription"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/procedureDescriptionTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bodyPartTitle"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/procedureTitle"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:text="This is a procedure description. It will be a long text"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedInAtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/procedureDescriptionTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/checked_in_at"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedInAtTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/procedureDescriptionTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/checkedInAtTitle"
        tools:text="5:00 PM"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/checkedInAtTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**DialogFragment xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    tools:context="com.alemhealth.ticketcapture.Features.CheckInListShow.StudyListDialog.CheckInDialogFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check_in_information"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/studyListRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/closeButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/studyListRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
        android:text="@string/close"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Custom theme for DialogFragment:**

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">57%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">57%</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
</style>
```

**onCreateView of DialogFragment:**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_check_in_dialog, container, false);

        StudyListForDialog studyListForDialog = (StudyListForDialog) getArguments().getSerializable("data");

        if(studyListForDialog!=null){
            toolbarTextView.setText(studyListForDialog.getPatientName() + " - " + studyListForDialog.getPatientAge() + " - " + studyListForDialog.getPatientGender());

            studyListRecyclerViewAdapter = new StudyListRecyclerViewAdapter(studyListForDialog, getActivity(), this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(studyListRecyclerViewAdapter);
        }    

        return view;
    }
```

**AND in this way I open my DialogFragment:**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("data", data);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity)view.getContext()).getFragmentManager();

CheckInDialogFragment checkInDialogFragment = new CheckInDialogFragment();
checkInDialogFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle);
checkInDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
checkInDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "check-in");
```

Please help me fix this weird problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be it's a bug of `ConstaintLayout`.

I updated my **DialogFragment XML root** with `LinearLayout` instead of ConstraintLayout. And it solved the **shrinking** problem.

My updated DialogFragment xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check_in_information"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/studyListRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
        android:text="@string/close"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```